# How can I iterate through multiple excel sheets to apply simple data cleaning to all sheets?

Tags: r

The issue I am having is that I need to iterate through multiple excel sheets and apply some simple data cleaning to each sheet. I can do it manually, however that is not efficient.

```
read_excel_allsheets <- function(filename, tibble = FALSE) {
    sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(filename)
    x <- lapply(sheets, function(X) readxl::read_excel(filename, sheet = X))
    if(!tibble) x <- lapply(x, as.data.frame)
    names(x) <- sheets
    x
}


Mega_sheets = read_excel_allsheets("Dealer.xlsx")
```

Now with the code above I can grab each excel sheet. I want to apply this:

```
colnames(Mega_sheets$`Feb - 18`) <- as.character(unlist(Mega_sheets$`Feb - 18`[6,]))
Mega_sheets$`Feb - 18` = Mega_sheets$`Feb - 18`[c(-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6), ]
```

The format of every sheet is the exact same.

How can I iterate through each sheet and apply the couple lines of data cleaning to each sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `lapply`, a `for` loop, `purrr::map`, etc. Here is an example with `lapply` which should work:

```
Mega_sheets <- lapply(Mega_sheets, function(x){
  colnames(x) <- as.character(unlist(x[6,]))
  x[c(-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6), ]
})
```